# How do I convert Points to Mesh in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I have created a tornado that is comprised of points, and I want to essentially skin the points to finalize the look of the tornado.  But I'm stuck here because I can't figure out how to convert the points to a solid mesh.  I can convert the points to vertices, but that's as far as I get.

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kwbo8ttwxlr59hj/Tornado%20GN%20Build.blend?dl=0)

Would love some tips, thanks.

[image]

Comment: I haven't thought this through, but "shrinkwrap" of an enclosing cylindar (subdivided side edges) comes to mind.

Comment: After convert it to verts you can put a highly subdivided cylinder or cone around it (a little manual shaping required), and use a Shrinkwrap modifier on it with "Nearest Vertex" Wrap Method.

Comment: Another option to create a mesh from points is the nodes *Points To Volume* and *Volume To Mesh*. Or if you use Cycles: it can render point clouds natively and very fast in Blender 3.x. Try *Density* = 380500 for the *Distribute Points on Faces* node to create a cloud with 1 million points.

Comment: non-Blender solution : Export to .obj, open in Cloudcompare, compute normals, do a poisson surface reconstruction. https://i.stack.imgur.com/whmBP.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. It would be good to know what you want to achieve, what the final result should look like. Do you want to keep the details and rotation?

Here is one example using Points to Volume and then Volume to Mesh:

[image]